# Connecting to MySQL through SSH tunnel and ForwardPrtLocal

Tags: mysql, windows-services

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database on a client server. The problem I have is happens when our MySQL on our local machine is running. I get an error from my windows service trying to connect to the client my sqlç

`An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions`

It seems our local my sql is using the 3306 port and blocks it. if I stop MySQL on our server and run the windows service it is fine. How can I get around this?

```
PasswordConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new PasswordConnectionInfo("########",####, "######", "#######");
connectionInfo.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(500);
SshClient client = new SshClient(connectionInfo);
client.Connect();
ForwardedPortLocal portFwld = new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1",3306,"127.0.0.1", 3306); client.AddForwardedPort(portFwld);portFwld.Start();
// using Renci.sshNet 
DBConnect connection = new DBConnect(portFwld);
```

Comment: Please next time write your question in better english and format.

Answer (score 0):

You can just forward client 3306 port on your local 3307 port.
Then use 3307 to connect to mysql.

You can test it by using putty for example :

[Putty example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Omwe.gif)

try this : var port = new ForwardedPortLocal("localhost", 3307, "your remote server", 3306);